# Webservice call in Play2 Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, playframework-2.1

I want to do something apparently simple: calling a webservice and saving the result in the database.

I'm inside an Akka Actor code and what I do is to call an object method:

```
object Service {
  def run {
    val response = WS.url("http://api.server.com/rest/")
    .withAuth("test", "test", com.ning.http.client.Realm.AuthScheme.BASIC)
    .get.value.get.get.body
  }
}
```

How do I parse the body? I tried to print it on the console but I got NotSuchElement exception.

Any idea, thought? How do I parse arrays, attributes, elements of the XML ?

I'm in the play version 2.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things have changed a bit since the previous version. Play 2.1.0 depends on the `scala.concurrent` package instead of their own classes:

- A Play `Promise` is now a Scala `Future`
- A Play `Redeemable` is now a Scala `Promise`

I didn't have time to test it, but from the documentation I gathered it should be something like this:

```
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

object WebserviceCallParseXML {

  val responseFuture = WS.url("http://api.server.com/rest/")
    .withAuth("test", "test", com.ning.http.client.Realm.AuthScheme.BASIC)
    .get()

  val resultFuture = responseFuture map { response =>
    response.status match {
      case 200 => Some(response.xml)
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  val result = Await.result(resultFuture, 5 seconds)

  println(if (result.isDefined) result.get else "No result found" )

}
```

The documentation about `Future.value`:

> If the future is not completed the returned value will be None. If the future is completed the value will be Some(Success(t)) if it contains a valid result, or Some(Failure(error)) if it contains an exception.

Comment: It works sweetly, nice try without testing! The last part of the question is missing though. How do I convert Some(response.xml) to a Case Class representing the XML ?

Comment: That is just normal Scala xml processing. Maybe this article could help you start: http://bcomposes.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/basic-xml-processing-with-scala/